# Node / Docker: "Cannot mind module" for server.js

Tags: node.js, docker, express, npm

I am trying to Dockerize a node application that has a client subfolder with a vue application. I keep getting an error, `Cannot find module '/app/dist/server.js'` when I run `npm start` in the main directory. Some relevant information:

Project Directory:

[image]

When running `npm run build-server` typescript compiles the `.ts` files into a `dist` folder:

[image]

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:15-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

# CD into client directory and npm install

RUN cd client && npm install

# CD back into main directory and npm install

RUN cd ..
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build-server

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: url-shortener
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
```

I am getting the following error when running `docker-compose.yml`. I can verify that `/app/dist/server.js` exists in the container but for some reason `ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]` is triggering the error.

```
app_1    | Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/server.js'
app_1    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
app_1    |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
app_1    |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
app_1    |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
app_1    |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
app_1    |   requireStack: []
app_1    | }
```

Comment: The `volumes:` hide everything that gets done in the Dockerfile, so when the container tries to run it sees the host's `./dist` directory instead of what gets produced by the `npm run build-server` command.  Delete that block from your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks, that was it :P I spent hours trying to figure that out...